# How can I update PMD to newer version?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-library, pmd

I have an Android library and an Android App project, what use [the library PMD](https://github.com/pmd/pmd).

We use an older version and I am asked to update this PMD library to a more recent version 6.X.X

In the project, I found a `rules-pmd.xml` file with:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> <ruleset
     name="My rules"
     xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0
http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_5_3_1.xsd">
```

Changing this xml to

```
http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_6_12_0.xsd
```

did not help. And then in the modules build.gradle:

```
apply from: "$path/script-pmd.gradle"
```

Could not find any other version for PMD..

**Where can I change the used PMD version?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the given question, you have to ask the libraries authors. Also you can take a look at the given [**library web link**](https://pmd.github.io/) for more information about that.

**Update** : in the given code you are seeing about making ruleset, as stated [here](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.12.0/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html) so you have to check somewhere else for that.

*For example,* i just checked and stated here you will find the needed information : [follow the link](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.12.0/pmd_projectdocs_committers_releasing.html#the-release-notes-and-docs)

```
The new version needs to be entered into _config.yml, e.g.:

pmd:
latestVersion: 6.0.0
latestVersionDate: 15th December 2017
```

[image: _config]

Comment: I searched my whole Android library project and I could neither find a `_config.yml` file nor a docs folder, where I could have created a brand new file.

Comment: Just found the way where to search. I will attach the image in the answer @NoamEpstein inside the docs folder you can find the version you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can check on the main homepage https://pmd.github.io which version is the latest. Currently PMD 6.12.0 is the latest version.

In your ruleset `pmd-rules.xml`, you are referencing the schema XSD. But here you need to reference https://pmd.sourceforge.io/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd since you are using the ruleset schema version 2 (btw. http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_5_3_1.xsd doesn't exist at all). However, this does not matter, since the ruleset is not validated against the schema when PMD loads it.

More relevant seems to be the file `script-pmd.gradle`. Do you have this file?
I guess, that there the [gradle pmd plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/pmd_plugin.html) is configured. This plugin has a property which controls the version of PMD: [toolVersion](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension:toolVersion)

For example, your configuration could be adjusted to look like this:

```
pmd {
  ignoreFailures = false
  sourceSets = [sourceSets.main]
  reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/reports/pmd")
  ruleSets = [],
  ruleSetFiles = files("pmd-rules.xml")
  toolVersion = "6.12.0"
}
```